# stuck with a simple python program "elif"

Tags: python, syntax

Hello I am having a trouble while doing my simple calculator code :D

```
def cal():

while True:

 print ("welcome to my calculator!")
 print("choose an operation")

 op = input(" +, - ,/ ,*")


if op == "+":

  num1 = float(input("enter your first number:"))
  num2 = float(input("enter your second number:"))

  print(str(num1 + num2)



elif op == "/":

  num1 = float(input("enter your first number:"))
  num2 = float(input("enter your second number:"))

  print(str(num1 / num2)


else:

break 



cal()
```

When ever I run the code it says *invalid syntax* at the *elif*

what is wrong here?

Comment: It's hard to tell with your indentation being 2 spaces

Comment: Missing parentheses on the print statement before the elif

Comment: `print(str(num1 + num2)` has two left parentheses and one left parenthesis. This is a problem. There are other lines like this as well. Make sure your parentheses match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a bunch of brackets. If you want to take your program further use this as a model:

```
# This function adds two numbers 
def add(x, y):
   return x + y

# This function subtracts two numbers 
def subtract(x, y):
   return x - y

# This function multiplies two numbers
def multiply(x, y):
   return x * y

# This function divides two numbers
def divide(x, y):
   return x / y

print("Select operation.")
print("1.Add")
print("2.Subtract")
print("3.Multiply")
print("4.Divide")

# Take input from the user 
choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4):")

num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))

if choice == '1':
   print(num1,"+",num2,"=", add(num1,num2))

elif choice == '2':
   print(num1,"-",num2,"=", subtract(num1,num2))

elif choice == '3':
   print(num1,"*",num2,"=", multiply(num1,num2))

elif choice == '4':
   print(num1,"/",num2,"=", divide(num1,num2))
else:
   print("Invalid input")
```

Answer (score 4):

You never closed the bracket on the print function. Same goes for the other `if` statement. You should use indentation of 4 spaces in the future, too.

```
if op == "+":
    num1 = float(input("enter your first number:"))
    num2 = float(input("enter your second number:"))
    print(str(num1 + num2))
```

Comment: you can use 4 spaces, but i just find using tab more convinient.

Comment: @Stack I always try to make my code as clean as possible, which also involves following [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)

Comment: It doesnt matter, tab gives the same number of spaces. It is just easy to press tab once than pressing space 4 times. Anyways follow what you want  : )

Comment: @Stack Sublime allows me to indent using spaces, hitting `tab` puts 4 spaces in the code. But you're right, this is really a matter of preference. :)